# Which HTML elements have properties with sub-properties?

Tags: javascript, html

All I can think of are `style` and `data`. Those attributes are accessible with JavaScript via `Element.style` and `Element.dataset` which are objects, and have properties accessible via syntax like `Element.style.fontSize` vs. attributes whose properties are Strings, like `Element.id` or attributes whose properties are Arrays such as `Element.classList`.

What are all of the HTML elements with attribute values that are accessible via object properties?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement

Comment: you should probably read the docs, the url provided by @JayHarris is a good start.

Comment: By the way, `id` has a special case, its element could be accessed as an object with the `id` value. i.e `<h1 id="hTitle">Text</h1>` could be accessed as `hTitle.innerText`

Comment: Thanks, I have read the documentation, and it's looking to me that style and data are the only object properties. I'm seeking conventional wisdom about well known object type properties I might have missed.